# Unreliable multi-peer communications

Tags: ios7, multipeer-connectivity

I'm having trouble getting multi-peer communications to work reliably. Peers are being arbitrarily lost and when the app moves to the background and then become active again, it is not clear what needs to be done to re-estate the communication. Any ideas?

Comment: Not quite a question yet.  Please ask about a single problem with code, log output, etc

Comment: There are many examples on SO that with a little extra searching you will find the techniques to employ to get reliability